# Python client connecting to large number of servers

Tags: networking, twisted, asyncore

How would one go around to **establish and maintain a large number of TCP connections** to several remote servers? When I say large think c10k large. 
It would be a sort of massively connected P2P app, that would aggressively seek out new peers.

This would involve using a **single outgoing TCP port, sort of like a server, receiving data in a single port** and processing it concurrently or asynchronously, but instead of listening on a port i would SYN out several remote server.
To implement this I would like to use a Linux/BSD OS and ideally using an async python networking lib.

I looked in the basic documentation of [asyncore](http://docs.python.org/2/library/asyncore.html) and [twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/index.html) and some basic searches here on stack overflow but I got no where near what I needed.

Can some one point me to a possible solution or at east some literature that does no involve diving (at least no to deeply) in OS level stuff.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why don't you use regular TCP connections instead?  10k TCP connections isn't going to strain Twisted much.  Either I don't understand the approach you're proposing instead, or it doesn't make any sense.  Either way, it doesn't seem necessary.